# How to set input type 'datetime-local' with min [today] at 08.00 to max [today] at 17.00 ? or set the max date [today] only?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm triny to set input type 'datetime-local' with min [today] at 08.00 to max [today] at 17.00 ? or set the max date [today] only ? i've haven't found any solution to set max date in today with the input type 'date-time-local

Sample :

```js
let dateInput = document.getElementById("dt");
dateInput.min = "2022-11-14T08:00";
dateInput.max = "2022-11-14T17:00";
```

```html
<input class="date form-control" type="datetime-local" id="dt" name="tanggal_eksekusi_qa" required>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem. Is the problem that you cannot dynamically set the `min` and `max` to today instead of specifying a specific date like `2022-11-14`?

Comment: @thabs yes !! i'm sorry if my problem or question is confusing

Answer (score -1):

```js
var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate(); //Current day
  var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear(); //(Year is 2022)
  var hh = today.getHours(); //Current hour
  var m = today.getMinutes(); //Current minutes

  if (dd < 10)
  {
      dd = '0' + dd;
  } 
  if (mm < 10)
  {
      mm = '0' + mm;
  }

  today_min = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd + "T08:00"; 
  //or Year-Month-Day
  today_max = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd + "T17:00";
  //or Year-Month-Day&Todayhour:minute
  document.getElementById("dt").setAttribute("min", today_min);
  document.getElementById("dt").setAttribute("max", today_max);
```

```html
          <input class="date form-control" type="datetime-local" id="dt" name="tanggal_eksekusi_op" required>
```